# What are examples of magazine-like front-pages in web design?

Tags: page-layout, information-design

I'm designing a responsive front-page layout for a well known online community (just dribbbled [this preview](http://dribbble.com/shots/423694-Responsive-layout-1)). The content section will feature a list of several articles, each containing:

1. A thumbnail;
2. A title;
3. An excerpt;
4. Related metadata.

There will be a minimum of two articles per row (up to four articles, maximum), just like in a magazine layout with an index of articles on its front-page. Right now I'm pursuing the correct balance between aesthetics and functionality while keeping a very clean and understandable layout. Unfortunately I'm miserably failing at it and I need some inspiration and examples of **magazine-like front-pages in web design** (listing articles with similar structure as the one listed above) that can help me to better structure my contents into this responsive layout. Some of the following examples could fit my needs:

- [Pitchfork](http://www.pitchfork.com/)
- [Design made in Germany](http://www.designmadeingermany.de/)

Sadly, that's all I got. Do you have any more examples of this kind of magazine-like layouts? Do you have any other feedback that could help me accomplish a layout that looks more like an online magazine front-page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if these fit all of your criteria, but here are a few of my favorite editorial type layouts:

- [The Verge](http://www.theverge.com/)
- [Wired](http://www.wired.com/)
- [The Great Discontent (mostly just pretty...maybe not exactly what you're looking for)](http://www.thegreatdiscontent.com/)

I also find [The Awwwards](http://www.awwwards.com/) to be a very good reference in times of inspirational need.

Hope that helps!

Comment: That's great help, @pdv. In fact, The Great Discontent's website is one of my favorite responsive designs.

Answer (score 0):

The only one I can think of offhand is an actual magazine: the NY Times's [one-page magazine](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2012/02/12/magazine/free-pony-candidate.html?ref=magazine) from the Sunday section.